# Profile picture on Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, profile-picture

It's been a month or so that I have started using Stack Exchange. Almost everytime I have noticed that my profile pic is different than it was before. The geometry as well as the color.

Can anyone explain why and how is it done? (for every user I guess?)

Comment: They are using (and you are using) Gravatar to generate that based on your email address. If you change your email or if Gravatar screws up / improves their algorithm (they have done so in the past) your profile pic will change.

Comment: Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Looks like you're using different emails on several sites, the default profile picture (which you're using) is based on email, and taking the picture from Gravatar. If you want same pic on all sites, upload your own, and choose to save changes on all sites, then you'll also have to synchronize on stackexchange.com manually, it's not automatic.